# WP_Query order by multiple meta keys & fields

Tags: wp-query, order

How to order query by multiple meta keys and fields/custom fields?

This is my code:

```
$args = array
    (
        'post_type' => 'listing',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array
        (
            array
            (
                'taxonomy' => 'listing_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => urldecode($category)
            ),
            array
            (
                'taxonomy' => 'location',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => urldecode($location)
            )
        ),

        //*** THIS NOT WORK
        'meta_query'    => array
        (
            array(
                'key'     => 'listing_status',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'listing_total_rank',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => DESC,
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'listing_free_date',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'title',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => ASC,
            ),
        ),
        //***
    );

$listings = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The part of `'meta_query'` does not working in the code.

Comment: I would note that this query is going to be quite slow/expensive

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using meta query without setting a value. The way you are doing it is using to query posts, not to order them.

### Using Named Meta Queries

To order your posts by different meta datas, you can give your meta queries a name and then use that to set the ordering. Here is a simple example for you:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'query_one' => array(
            'key' => 'key_one',
            'value' => 'value_one', // Optional
        ),
        'query_two' => array(
            'key' => 'key_two',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS', // Optional
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 
        'query_one' => 'ASC',
        'query_two' => 'DESC',
    ),
);
```

You can check [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) section of codex page for `WP_Query()` to familiarize yourself with sorting the posts.